# What is it about a light bulb that makes the resistence greater as the voltage increases?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

I have a question on one of my physics labs that I do not exactly know how to answer.

Question:
Is the resistance for larger voltages greater than, less than, or equal to the resistance at smaller voltages? What is it about the light bulb that would make its resistance behave the way it does?

From the data I collected, it seems to me that the resistance is greater at greater voltages.

Given $V=IR$; some data points for V and I:

Smaller $V$ values:
.174V/.083mA = 2.096V/mA
.446V/.131mA = 3.404V/mA
1.010V/.189mA = 5.344V/mA

Greater $V$ values:
4.120V/.391mA = 10.537V/mA
4.950V/.428mA = 11.565V/mA
6.37V/.483mA = 13.188V/mA

I was thinking that the light bulbs resistance behaves this way because as the light bulbs voltage increases, the energy also increases, so I was thinking maybe it has something to do with power - $P=I^2R$?

Since it is a direct relationship, if $V$ increases then $I$ must decrease, so dividing by a really small number will create a bigger resistance in that equation. Does the increase in heat also increase the resistance? Why?

Comment: Hint: Resistance is temperature-dependent.

Comment: ok I think I understand

Comment: Next question:  *Why* is resistance temperature dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrical resistance is temperature dependent. Higher voltages imply larger current from $V=IR$, which leads to more heat generated by $H=I^2R$.

Here's my intuitive way of understanding why resistance changes with temperature. Resistance comes about because as the electron moves along the wire, it slams into the atoms that make up the wire. As the temperature increases, the atoms of the wire jiggle more - they vibrate around their position. Clearly if the atoms are jiggling more, a passing electron is also more likely to slam into them, and therefore the resistance increases.

This picture works fine for metals, but not for some non-metals where the number of free electrons increases with temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The tungsten metal from which the bulb's filament is made has the property that as its temperature increases, its resistivity does up. Since the temperature of a filament goes way up as it gets fully hot, its resistance climbs significantly, and as it heats up, the current flow through it goes down.

Comment: Increasing resistance with temperature is generally true for metals